# API with hug Framework on Windows Server 2012R2 with IIS8

Tags: iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2, hug

I am trying to get a hug api running on a windows Server 2012 R2.
I configuered the server like seen in an Django Example([here](http://blog.mattwoodward.com/2016/07/running-django-application-on-windows.html)).

I created a virtual enviroment and installed hug. If I try to run the happy_birthday example with the command:

> python -m hug -f happy_birthday.py

I get an error with the message:

> "C:\virtualenvs\foo\Scripts\python.exe: No module named hug.__ main
>   __; 'hug' is a package an cannot be directly executed"

Why do I get this Error and how can I solve it?

Comment: What happens if you run `hug -f happy_birthday.py` instead of  `python -m hug -f happy_birthday.py`?

Comment: didn't work too. the error message was something like: hug is an unknown statement.